# Entity Framework Projecting Multiple Models to Single DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dto

I want to ask how to map multiple model objects to a single DTO.

I have the following EF models as follows:

**Bracket.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("Bracket")]
    public partial class Bracket
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Bracket()
        {
            Teams = new HashSet<Team>();
        }

        public int BracketId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string BracketName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Team.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("Team")]
    public partial class Team
    {
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string TeamName { get; set; }

        public int BracketId { get; set; }

        public virtual Bracket Bracket { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I created DTO objects to represent them.

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class BracketDto
    {
        public int BracketId { get; set; }

        public string BracketName { get; set; }

        public List<TeamDto> Teams { get; set; }
    }

    public class TeamDto
    {
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        public string TeamName { get; set; }

        public int BracketId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In one of my class I use to query the database and project the resulting data, this is what I am doing:

```
public List<BracketDto> GetBrackets()
        {
            var brackets = (from a in this.Context.Brackets
                            join b in this.Context.Teams on a.BracketId equals b.BracketId
                            select new BracketDto()
                            {
                                BracketId = a.BracketId,
                                BracketName = a.BracketName
                            }).ToList<BracketDto>();

            var teams = (from a in this.Context.Teams
                         select new TeamDto()
                         {
                             TeamId = a.TeamId,
                             TeamName = a.TeamName,
                             BracketId = a.BracketId
                         }).ToList<TeamDto>();

            foreach(BracketDto bracket in brackets)
            {
                var tl = teams.Where(a => a.BracketId == bracket.BracketId).ToList();
                bracket.Teams = tl;
            }

            var xtra = (from a in this.Context.Brackets
                        join b in this.Context.Teams on a.BracketId equals b.BracketId
                        select new BracketDto()
                        {
                            BracketId = a.BracketId,
                            BracketName = a.BracketName
                        }).ToList<BracketDto>();

            return brackets;
        }
```

Where I am getting results:

```
[
    {
        "BracketId": 1,
        "BracketName": "Eastern Conference",
        "Teams": [
            {
                "TeamId": 1,
                "TeamName": "Indiana Pacers",
                "BracketId": 1
            },
            {
                "TeamId": 3,
                "TeamName": "Cleveland Cavaliers",
                "BracketId": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "BracketId": 2,
        "BracketName": "Western Conference",
        "Teams": [
            {
                "TeamId": 2,
                "TeamName": "Los Angeles Lakers",
                "BracketId": 2
            },
            {
                "TeamId": 4,
                "TeamName": "Los Angeles Clippers",
                "BracketId": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I know that there could be a more efficient way to do this. But I am quite unsure how to do it on the LINQ query I have.

Looking for advise and suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the relationships in place, you just need to take advantage of them.

```
public List<BracketDto> GetBrackets()
{
    var brackets = this.Context.Brackets.Select(a => {
        return new BracketDto(){
            BracketId = a.BracketId,
            BracketName = a.BracketName,
            Teams = a.Teams.Select(b => {
                  return new TeamDto() {
                    TeamId = b.TeamId,
                    TeamName = b.TeamName,
                    BracketId = b.BracketId
                };
            }).ToList()
        };
    }).ToList();

    return brackets;
}
```